# Laravel 5: How can I pass a variable from a controller method to app.blade.php?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm showing a variable in my layout file app.blade.php. That variable has a default value defined in my global 'view composer'. I need to overwrite that value from within a controller method, how can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried with `view()->share('variable', value)` in your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a tricky one. The problem is that the view composer gets trigger after the controller has returned the view. However you can check inside the view composer if the value has been set:

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    if(!$view->offsetExists('foo')){
        $view->with('foo', 'default');
    }
}
```

And when you want to "override" the default in your controller:

```
return view('view.name')->with('foo', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you may use something like this:

```
$view = view('view.name')->with(...); // This will trigger the composer
```

This will return the rendered (composer ran already) `View` then you may set the value into the variable using something like this:

```
$view->variablename = 'value'; // You may also check it using $view->offsetExists(...)
```

Then return the view like:

```
return $view;
```

Comment: Looks like the composer is still running after and overwritting the values